# Show unique and viewable profile page for each user using Flask

Tags: flask

I have created unique user pages for each person who registers to this social app by using the following:

```
@app.route("/profile/<username>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def profile(username):
    user = session["user"] or None
    # grab the session user's username from db
    username = mongo.db.users.find_one(
        {"username": session["user"]})["username"]
    user_profile = mongo.db.users.find_one({"username": user})
    
    if session["user"]:
        return render_template("profile.html", username=username, profile=user_profile)

    return redirect(url_for("login"))
```

This creates a unique username profile built up from edited data that the user puts in. But I want to be able to view that profile from another user's login and then add them as a friend (if I choose).

Because I already have a URL created /profile/ do I need to create a new `@app.route` to something such as `view_profile/<username>`?

From there, I would use the Post and Get methods so if someone wanted to add that user as a friend they could click on that. From there, I think I would need the other user to accept the friend request? Not quite sure how to get to that just yet. But one step at a time I guess.

I started with the idea of a view_profile @app.route but now I am not 100% sure which direction to take it that will make the next stages also easy.